# How can I make a universal construction more efficient?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

A "universal construction" is a wrapper class for a sequential object that enables it to be linearized (a strong consistency condition for concurrent objects). For instance, here's an adapted wait-free construction, in Java, from [1], which presumes the existence of a wait-free queue that satisfies the interface `WFQ` (which only requires one-time consensus between threads) and assumes a `Sequential` interface:

```java
public interface WFQ<T> // "FIFO" iteration
{
    int enqueue(T t); // returns the sequence number of t
    Iterable<T> iterateUntil(int max); // iterates until sequence max
}
public interface Sequential
{
    // Apply an invocation (method + arguments)
    // and get a response (return value + state)
    Response apply(Invocation i); 
}
public interface Factory<T> { T generate(); } // generate new default object
public interface Universal extends Sequential {}

public class SlowUniversal implements Universal
{
    Factory<? extends Sequential> generator;
    WFQ<Invocation> wfq = new WFQ<Invocation>();
    Universal(Factory<? extends Sequential> g) { generator = g; } 
    public Response apply(Invocation i)
    {
        int max = wfq.enqueue(i);
        Sequential s = generator.generate();
        for(Invocation invoc : wfq.iterateUntil(max))
            s.apply(invoc);
        return s.apply(i);
    }
}
```

This implementation isn't very satisfying since it is really slow (you remember every invocation, and have to replay it at every apply - we have linear runtime in the history size). Is there any way that we could extend the `WFQ` and `Sequential` interfaces (in reasonable ways) to enable us to save some steps when applying a new invocation?

Can we make this more efficient (not linear runtime in history size, preferably memory usage goes down too) without losing the wait-free property?

**Clarification**

A "universal construction" is a term I'm pretty sure was made up by [1] which accepts a thread-unsafe but thread-compatible object, which is generalized by the `Sequential` interface. Using a wait-free queue, the first construction offers a thread-safe, *linearizable* version of the object that's also wait-free (this assumes determinism and halting `apply` operations).

This is inefficient, since the method is effectively to have each local thread start from a clean slate and applies **every** operation ever recorded to it. In any case, this works because it achieves synchronization effectively by using the `WFQ` to determine the order in which all operations should be applied: every thread calling `apply` will see the same local `Sequential` object, with the same sequence of `Invocation`s applied to it.

My question is whether we can (e.g.) introduce a background cleanup process which updates the "starting state" so that we don't have to restart from scratch. This isn't as simple as having an atomic pointer with a starting pointer - these kinds of approaches easily lose the wait-free guarantee. My suspicion is that some other queue-based approach might work here.

Jargon:

1. wait-free - regardless of the number of threads or the scheduler's decision making, `apply` will terminate in a provably bounded number of instructions executed for that thread.
2. lock-free - same as above, but admits the possibility of an unbounded execution time, only in the case that an unbounded number of `apply` operations are getting done in other threads. Typically, optimistic synchronization schemes fall into this category.
3. blocking - efficiency at the mercy of the scheduler.

[A working example, as requested (now on a page that won't expire)](https://gist.github.com/vlad17/bdeddc9b240e7975040f34f6dea23533)

[1] Herlihy and Shavit, *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*.

Comment: Question 1 is only answerable if we know what "works" means to you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I corrected it - all it needs to "work" is for the wrapper to be wait-free and all operations on `CopyableSequential` to be valid - linearizability should then follow from the fact that it's `Sequential`.

Comment: There are lots of meaningful words in this question but I'm struggling to put them together to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you provide some explanation of what problem you are trying to solve and maybe thin out the jargon a bit?

Comment: @JimmyJames I've elaborated in an "extended comment" inside the question. Please let me know if there's any other Jargon to clear up.

Comment: in the first paragraph of the comment you say "thread-unsafe but thread-compatible object" and "linearizable version of the object".  It's unclear what you mean by that because *thread-safe* and *linearizable* are only truly relevant to executable instructions but you are using them to describe objects, which are data.  I presume that *Invocation* (which isn't defined) is effectively a method pointer and it's that method that is not thread-safe.  I don't know what *thread-compatible* means.

Comment: @JimmyJames I'm using terminology which originated from google: [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp09263/) is a good summary. Any object can indeed be _linearizable_ - this means that all threads will agree that the object is equivalent to an object that was produced from a single history of atomic method invocations on one thread.

Comment: If you'll note in that link that it discusses thread-safe *classes* but no mention of a thread-safe *object*.  Most of this time it's too pedantic to make this distinction but when you are noodling about threading at this level it's really crucial that you are clear about the fact that thread-safety is only relevant in executable code which in Java means methods or method-like sections of code (i.e. initializers.) [cont]

Comment: Your definition of a *linearizable object* would appear to be equivalent to having synchronized an object's state across all threads with references to it i.e. one of the effects of the **synchronized** keyword in java.  I found this definition of [Linearizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) which only refers to operations but if you have one that refers to the state of objects, then it might be helpful to provide it.  Much of the code in both your question and answer are missing.  It would also be helpful to provide is as well as a working example of use.

Comment: @JimmyJames synchronized would give a stronger guarantee. Linearizability simply requires a consistent history to exist, synchronized causes there to be exactly one.

Invocation and Response aren't meant to have definitions. They don't really matter, and even undefined they capture the notion of some stateful operation on a `Sequential`. I'm using the exact same vocabulary and abstractions as the book. Because of this (desired) generality, an example probably has little meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation and example of how this is accomplished.  Let me know if there are parts that aren't clear.

[Gist with source](https://gist.github.com/James-Matthew-Watson/b724f3b61f5759071b104563d0d8a0e6)

## Universal

### Initialization:

Thread indexes are applied in a atomically incremented fashion.  This is managed using an `AtomicInteger` named `nextIndex`.  These indexes are assigned to threads through a `ThreadLocal` instance which initializes itself by getting the next index from `nextIndex` and incrementing it.  This happens the first time each thread's index is retrieved the first time.
A `ThreadLocal` is created to track the last sequence this thread created.  It's initialized 0.
The sequential factory object reference is passed in and stored.
Two `AtomicReferenceArray` instances are created of size `n`.  The tail object is assigned to each reference, having been initialized with the initial state provided by the `Sequential` factory.  `n` is the maximum number of threads allowed.  Each element in these arrays 'belongs' to corresponding thread index.

### Apply method:

This is the method that does the interesting work.  It does the following:

- Create a new node for this invocation: mine
- Set this new node in the announce array at the current thread's index

Then the sequencing loop begins.  It will continue until the current invocation has been sequenced:

1. find a node in the announce array using the sequence of the last node created by this thread.  More on this later.
2. if a node is found in step 2 it is not yet sequenced, continue with it, otherwise, just focus on the current invocation.  This will only try to help one other node per invocation.
3. Whatever node was selected in step 3, keep trying to sequence it after the last sequenced node (other threads may interfere.)  Regardless of success, set the current threads head reference to the sequence returned by `decideNext()`

The key to the nested loop described above is the `decideNext()` method.  To understand that, we need to look at the Node class.

## Node class

This class specifies nodes in a doubly-linked list.  There's not a lot of action in this class.  Most of the methods are simple retrieval methods that should be fairly self-explanatory.

### tail method

this returns a special node instance with a sequence of 0.  It simply acts as a place-holder until an invocation replaces it.

### Properties and initialization

- `seq`: the sequence number, initialized to -1 (meaning unsequenced)
- `invocation`: the value of the invocation of `apply()`.  Set upon construction.
- `next`: `AtomicReference` for the forward link.  once assigned, this will never be changed
- `previous`: `AtomicReference` for the backward link assigned upon sequencing and cleared by `truncate()`

### Decide Next

This method is only one in Node with non-trivial logic.  In a nutshell, a node is offered as a candidate to be the next node in the linked list.  The `compareAndSet()` method will check if it's reference is null and if so, set the reference to the candidate.  If the reference is already set, it does nothing.  This operation is atomic so if two candidates are offered at the same moment, only one will be selected.  This guarantees only one node will ever be selected as the next one.  If the candidate node is selected, it's sequence is set to the next value, and it's previous link is set to this node.

## Jumping Back to the Universal class apply method ...

Having called `decideNext()` on the last sequenced node (when checked) with either our node or a node from the `announce` array, there are two possible occurrences:
 1. The node was successfully sequenced
 2. Some other thread pre-empted this thread.

The next step is to check whether the node created for this invocation.  This could happen because this thread successfully sequenced it or some other thread picked it up from the `announce` array and sequenced it for us.  If it has not been sequenced, the process is repeated. Otherwise the call finishes up by clearing the announce array for at this thread's index and returning the result value of the invocation.  The announce array is cleared to guarantee there are no references to the node left around that would prevent the node from being garbage collected and therefore keep all nodes in the linked list from that point on alive on the heap.

### Evaluate method

Now that the invocation's node has been successfully sequenced, the invocation needs to be evaluated.  To do that, the first step is to ensure that the invocations preceding this one have been evaluated.  If they haven't this thread will not wait but will do that work immediately.

#### EnsurePrior method

The `ensurePrior()` method does this work by checking the previous node in the linked list.  If it's state is not set, the previous node will be evaluated.  Node that this is recursive.  If the node prior to prior node has not been evaluated, it will call evaluate for that node and so on an so forth.

Now that the previous node is known to have a state, we can evaluate this node.  The last node is retrieved and assigned to a local variable.  If this reference is null, it means that some other thread has pre-empted this one and already evaluated this node; setting it's state.  Otherwise, the prior node's state is passed to the `Sequential` object's apply method along with this node's invocation.  The state returned is set on the node and the `truncate()` method is called, clearing the backward link from the node as it is no longer needed.

#### MoveForward method

The move forward method will attempt to move all head references to this node if they are not already pointing to something further along.  This is to ensure that if a thread stops calling, it's head will not retain a reference to an node that is no longer needed.  The `compareAndSet()` method will make sure we only update the node if some other thread hasn't changed it since it was retrieved.

## Announce array and helping

The key to making this approach wait-free as opposed to simply lock-free is that we can't assume that the thread scheduler will give each thread priority when it needs it.  If each thread simply attempted to sequence it's own nodes, it's possible that a thread could be continually pre-empted under load.  To account for this possibility each thread will first try to 'help' other threads that may be unable to get sequenced.

The basic idea is that as each thread successfully creates nodes, the sequences assigned are monotonically increasing.  If a thread or threads are continually pre-empting another thread, the index the use to find unsequenced nodes in the `announce` array will move forward.  Even if every thread that is currently trying to sequence a given node is continually pre-empted by another thread, eventually all threads will be trying to sequence that node.  To illustrate, we'll construct an example with three threads.

At the starting point, all three threads' head and announce elements are pointed at the `tail` node.  The `lastSequence` for each thread is 0.

At this point, *Thread 1* is executed with an invocation.  It checks the announce array for it's last sequence (zero) which is the node it is currently scheduled to index.  It sequences the node and it's `lastSequence` is set to 1.

*Thread 2* is now executed with an invocation, it checks the announce array at it's last sequence (zero) and sees that it doesn't need help and so attempts to sequence it's invocation.  It succeeds and now it's `lastSequence` is set to 2.

*Thread 3* is now executed and it also sees that the node at `announce[0]` is already sequenced and sequences it's own invocation.  It's `lastSequence` is now set to 3.

Now *Thread 1* is invoked again.  It checks the announce array at index 1 and finds that it's already sequenced.  Concurrently, *Thread 2* is invoked.  It checks the announce array at index 2 and finds that it is already sequenced.  Both *Thread 1* and *Thread 2* now attempt to sequence their own nodes.  *Thread 2* wins and it sequences it's invocation.  It's `lastSequence` is set to 4.  Meanwhile, thread three has been invoked.  It checks the index it `lastSequence` (mod 3) and finds that the node at `announce[0]` has not been sequenced.  *Thread 2* is again invoked at the same time that *Thread 1* is on it's second attempt.  *Thread 1* finds an unsequenced invocation at `announce[1]` which is the node just created by *Thread 2*.  It attempts to sequence *Thread 2's* invocation and succeeds.  *Thread 2* finds it's own node at `announce[1]` and it has been sequenced.  It set's it's `lastSequence` to 5.  *Thread 3* is then invoked and finds that node that thread 1 placed at `announce[0]` is still not sequenced and attempts to do so.  Meanwhile *Thread 2* has also been invoked and pre-empts Thread 3.  It sequences it's node and sets it's `lastSequence` to 6.

Poor *Thread 1*.  Even though *Thread 3* is trying to sequence it, both threads have been continually thwarted by the scheduler.  But at this point. *Thread 2* is also now pointing to `announce[0]` (6 mod 3).  All three threads are set to attempt to sequence the same invocation.  No matter which thread succeeds, the next node to be sequenced will be the waiting invocation of *Thread 1* i.e. the node referenced by `announce[0]`.

This is inevitable.  In order for threads to be pre-empted, other threads must be sequencing nodes and as they do so, they will continually move their `lastSequence` ahead.  If a given thread's node is continually not sequenced, eventually all the threads will be pointing to it's index in the announce array.  No thread will do anything else until the node it is trying to help has been sequenced, the worst case scenario is that all threads are pointing to the same unsequenced node.  Therefore, the time required to sequence any invocation is a function of the number of threads and not the size of the input.

Comment: Would you mind putting some of the code excerpts on pastebin? A lot of things (like the lockfree linked list) can be simply stated as such? It's a bit difficult to understand your answer as a whole when there are so many details. In any case, this looks promising, I'd certainly like to dig into what guarantees it provides.

Comment: This certainly seems like a valid lock-free implementation, but it's missing the fundamental issue I'm worried about. The requirement of linearizability necessitates a "valid history" to be present, which, in the case of linked-list implementation, needs a `previous` and `next` pointer to be valid. Maintaining and creating a valid history in a wait-free manner seems hard.

Comment: @VF1 I'm not sure what issue is not addressed.  Everything you mention in the rest of the comment is addressed in the example I gave, from what I can tell.

Comment: You've given up the *wait-free* property.

Comment: @VF1 How do you figure?

Comment: The line `while (!prefer.isSequenced()) { head.set(getIndex(), max().decideNext(prefer)); }` may delayed indefinitely with just 2 threads, with one of them making progress forever.

Comment: @VF1 If you mean because other threads can 'cut in' indefinitely, that's not particular to this implementation.  If you look at the presentation in the link it's an issue for basic (run through everything) implementation too.  It has an explanation for how to address that but it seemed tangential to your question.  It may or may not be required based on the environment the application is running in.  Left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: It's not tangential to the question; it's the crux of it. The whole point for me posting my answer was to acknowledge that the universal construction is easy as soon as we give away the wait-free property. But then we're not making the construction more efficient; we're trading properties of wait-freedom for bounded memory. My question is hard because I'm asking if we can have both.

Comment: @VF1 Because you were unwilling to give a full working example, I found something which I felt comfortable was correct to base the answer on.  It seems to me that if you were to take your wait-free-queue based implementation, and when you walk the queue, you simply ensure each prior answer has been calculated and keep the last answer.  When you get to your question, you have the prior value.

Comment: I didn't have an issue with your providing a full working example. I just needed to make my post terse so that it's more readable. I'm not downvoting your answer, since I think it's useful to have a lock-free implementation for people (like yourself) that need the full working example for understanding. However, extending to a wait-free is not as easy as you describe it (I've tried your method). Try to get it working or demonstrate it rigorously - it's not so simple.

Comment: It's been weeks since I looked at this and I've moved on to other issues.  If you provide a working baseline (terseness is undesirable at this point), I'll might take a shot at it.

Comment: What do you mean by working baseline? You've already offered a lock-free baseline. If you're looking for a wait-free queue, see [java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

Comment: @VF1 You give an example code of a wait free universal construction.  It doesn't compile much less work.  If you update it to a working example, I will take a whack at taking the concept here and applying it to that.

Comment: I still feel strongly that it adds almost nothing (indeed, about two lines changed), [but here you go](https://goo.gl/VfWlVM).

Comment: @VF1 I don't see code that will compile in either your answer or question.

Comment: In the question, click on the words "A working example, as requested"

Comment: I wasn't trying to mess with you - is something wrong? Edit - it seems the link to the online coding website must've expired. I'm serious. I'll upload the zip I have (again, I'll post on my question).

Comment: @VF1 When I followed the link it took me to a tutorials site.  I'll just chalk that up to a coincidence.  I believe using link minifiers is discouraged here if not banned.

Comment: That site hosts live code (for an apparently short amount of time). It's what gave me that link, which, upon expiry, seems to redirect to their home page. In any case, git should work.

Comment: I've added some changes to this to address the issues you brought up.  Let me know if you have questions or see bugs, issues, etc.

Comment: OK, I've made several attempts at understanding this, but I can't. There are couple things in the way of my doing so:
(1) There seems to be a departure from the original types I drew up. I intentionally chose opaque non-generics `Invocation,Response` to avoid confusion. (2) `State` doesn't add anything. The state of a computation is captured by the state of the `Sequential` instance. (3) This is only code. There's no approach described or even an informal argument for the wait-free property.

As has been made clear on this Q&A many times, code is easier written than read.

Comment: For the above reason, I think it would really benefit your answer to deal on a prosaic, but precise level, deferring to psuedo-code if needed.

That's the level of abstraction that best answers this question. I.e., from your answer, I can see a promising approach based on co-operative reference advancing via an array with per-thread views into a central queue data structure.

I'm not trying to disparage the approach - I think it may be successful, but  as you can see from the lack of upvotes it's just un-analyzable by other users (including myself).

Comment: I can write up a description of the approach but I'm a little taken aback by the statement "State doesn't add anything" given that 1. it was in every other version of the code I've put here and you never mentioned it.  And 2. that it's the crux of the solution to avoid 'starting from scratch'.  How can you think it doesn't add anything?  This code will compile and run.  Try removing it and see what happens.  As far as the wait-free stuff goes, it should be clear to you that what I understand of that comes mostly from trying to answer this question.  I'm attempting to address your critiques

Comment: One issue is that the basic wait-free universal solution was based on a presentation I found searching on the terms in your question.  It now seems that this presentation has been removed from the public internet with a message that it is only available to students of the university.  I gather that the fact it was publicly available before was a mistake.  I can attempt to argue for the wait-free details but I don't feel comfortable plagiarizing that document.  Informal hand-waving is all I will be able to muster.

Comment: Do you want just a text explanation or do you want me to annotate the code?

Comment: I agree the state is crucial - it's just redundant. The members of the `Sequential` object, whatever they may be, encapsulate that state. Adding a generic `S` instead of `Sequential` just adds more syntax to the mix. I don't understand your point about plagiarism - just cite the document, perhaps? Both types of explanations would help, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51684/discussion-between-jimmyjames-and-vf1).

Comment: @VF1 Explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer doesn't really answer the question properly but as the OP sees it as useful, I will leave it as is.  Based on the code in the link in the question, here's my attempt.  I've done only really basic testing on this but it appears to calculate averages properly.  Feedback welcomed as to whether this is properly wait-free.

**NOTE**: I removed the Universal interface and made it a class.  Having Universal be composed of Sequentials as well as being one seems like an unnecessary complication but I might be missing something.  In the average class, I have marked the state variable to be `volatile`.  This isn't necessary to make the code work.  To be conservative (a good idea with threading) and prevent each thread from doing all the calculations (one time).

## Sequential & Factory

```
public interface Sequential<E, S, R>
{ 
  R apply(S priorState);

  S state();

  default boolean isApplied()
  {
    return state() != null;
  }
}

public interface Factory<E, S, R>
{
   S initial();

   Sequential<E, S, R> generate(E input);
}
```

## Universal

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class Universal<I, S, R> 
{
  private final Factory<I, S, R> generator;
  private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Sequential<I, S, R>> wfq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
  private final ThreadLocal<Sequential<I, S, R>> last = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public Universal(Factory<I, S, R> g)
  { 
    generator = g;
  }

  public R apply(I invocation)
  {
    Sequential<I, S, R> newSequential = generator.generate(invocation);
    wfq.add(newSequential);

    Sequential<I, S, R> last = null;
    S prior = generator.initial(); 

    for (Sequential<I, S, R> i : wfq) {
      if (!i.isApplied() || newSequential == i) {
        R r = i.apply(prior);

        if (i == newSequential) {
          wfq.remove(last.get());
          last.set(newSequential);

          return r;
        }
      }

      prior = i.state();
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("Houston, we have a problem");
  }
}
```

## Average

```
public class Average implements Sequential<Integer, Average.State, Double>
{
  private final Integer invocation;
  private volatile State state;

  private Average(Integer invocation)
  {
    this.invocation = invocation;
  }

  @Override
  public Double apply(State prior)
  {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + invocation + " prior " + prior);

    state = prior.add(invocation);

    return ((double) state.sum)/ state.count;
  }

  @Override
  public State state()
  {
    return state;
  }

  public static class AverageFactory implements Factory<Integer, State, Double> 
  {
    @Override
    public State initial()
    {
      return new State(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Average generate(Integer i)
    {
      return new Average(i);
    }
  }

  public static class State
  {
    private final int sum;
    private final int count;

    private State(int sum, int count)
    {
      this.sum = sum;
      this.count = count;
    }

    State add(int value)
    {
      return new State(sum + value, count + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
      return sum + " / " + count;
    }
  }
}
```

## Demo code

```
private static final int THREADS = 10;
private static final int SIZE = 50;

public static void main(String... args)
{
  Average.AverageFactory factory = new Average.AverageFactory();

  Universal<Integer, Average.State, Double> universal = new Universal<>(factory);

  for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
  {
    new Thread(new Test(i * SIZE, universal)).start();
  }
}

static class Test implements Runnable
{
  final int start;
  final Universal<Integer, Average.State, Double> universal;

  Test(int start, Universal<Integer, Average.State, Double> universal)
  {
    this.start = start;
    this.universal = universal;
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    for (int i = start; i < start + SIZE; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + i);

      System.out.println(System.nanoTime() + " " + Thread.currentThread() + " " + i + " result " + universal.apply(i));
    }
  }
}
```

I made some edits to the code as I was posting it here.  It should be OK but let me know if you have issues with it.

Comment: You don't have to keep your other answer up for me (I've previously updated my question to have any relevant conclusions to be drawn from it). Unfortunately, this answer doesn't answer the question either, since it doesn't actually free any of the memory in the `wfq`, so you still have to traverse through the entire history - the runtime hasn't improved except by a constant factor.

Comment: @Vf1 The time it takes to traverse through the entire list to check whether it has been calculated is going to be miniscule compared to doing each calculation.  Because the previous states are not required, it should be possible to remove the initial states.  Testing is difficult and it might require using a customized collection but I've added a small change.

Comment: @VF1 Updated to an implementation that seems to work with basic cursory testing.  I'm not sure it's safe but off the top of my head, if the universal was aware of the threads that are working with it, it could keep track of each thread and remove elements once all threads are safely past them.

Comment: @VF1 Looking at the code for ConcurrentLinkedQueue, the offer method has a loop much like the one that you claimed made the other answer non-wait-free.  Look for the comment "Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next"

Comment: "It should be possible to remove the initial states" - exactly. It _should be_, but its easy to subtly introduce code that loses wait freedom. A thread-tracking scheme might work. Finally, I don't have access to the CLQ source, would you mind linking?

Comment: Looking at the paper mentioned in the CLQ docs, the queue appears to be merely lock-free (and mis-documented). The paper only implements a lock-free queue. Perhaps the Java developers made extensions to the CLQ. In any case, for the purposes of an answer, I'm OK with just an _assumption_ that the docs are correct (wait free queues exist: [here's one](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~erez/Papers/wfquque-ppopp.pdf)).

Comment: @VF1 The paper describes an algorithm with the same kind of attempt-check loop that you claim is not wait-free.  What definition of wait-free are you using.  Is it possible that 'wait-free' just means that the thread is never put into a wait state?

Comment: No. The definition of wait-free is the same as in the paper I linked (bounded wait times i.e. O(1) always). The CLQ paper mentions wait-freedom about a _different_ implementation, but never claims it holds. However, the paper I linked above is formally wait free.

Comment: @VF1 Your question is whether it's possible to do this.  The paper you reference shows a queue implementation based on a linked-list that is wait free.  So we know that is possible.  I've shown that value can be calculated without the entire sequence of invocations.  The only thing left is whether the head of the linked list can be removed in a thread-safe manner.  Do you doubt that is possible?

Comment: Yes, I *do doubt* that the head of the linked list can *continually* be removed in a *thread-safe* and *wait-free manner*.

Comment: @VF1 OK.  I'll try to demonstrate when I have some time.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Please @mention me when you do.